# How to remove dots and page number of list of figures and list of tables in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

Heydo!

I need to include the first pages to TOC and NOT include page numbers. How I can I achieve this? \listoffigures and \listoftables makes a dotted line and a page number to TOC which I want to get rid of. I've searched for a number of questions but I always find answers to remove page number IN toc, which I have done already.

My table of contents should look like this:

```
ABSTRACT
LIST OF FIGURES
LIST OF TABLES
CONTENTS
CHAPTER 1...................................6
CHAPTER 2...................................7
```

Minimal working example:

```
% docmentclass
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% table of contents package 
\usepackage{tocloft}        

% package to enable commands after pages
\usepackage{afterpage}      

% dots to TOC
\AtBeginDocument{                                               
    \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}    
    \renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}                         
    \renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}                      
    \renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
    \renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
    }

%remove incremental number from TOC
\let\oldsection\section 
\newcommand{
    \abstractsection}[1]{ 
      \newpage
      \oldsection*{#1}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    }

%for captions to show up in lof and lot
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

%frontcover
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{5cm}
    \normalsize{Tuomas-Matti Soikkeli} \\
    \large{Front Cover}
    \vfill{}
\end{center} 

%abstract
\abstractsection{ABSTRACT}
Some abstract content
\newpage

%list of figures and list of tables
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF TABLES}
\newpage

%ToC
\tableofcontents 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CONTENTS}
\newpage

%contents
\section{FIRST CHAPTER}
\begin{figure}[H]
  figure
  \caption[EXAMPLE FIGURE]{example figure}
\end{figure}

\section{SECOND CHAPTER}
\begin{table}[h]
table
\caption[EXAMPLE TABLE]{example table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Ends up being:

[image: TOC.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use some of the functionality provided by [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft). Instead of using `\addcontentsline{<file>}{<type>}{<title>}`, use `\cftaddtitleline{<file>}{<type>}{<title>}{<page>}`. Using the latter allows you to use an empty `<page>` argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Table of Contents package 
\usepackage{tocloft}        

% dots to TOC
\AtBeginDocument{                                               
  \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}    
  \renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}                         
  \renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}                      
  \renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
  \renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
}

%remove incremental number from TOC
\newcommand{\abstractsection}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \section*{#1}
  \cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{#1}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecleader}{\hfill}}

%abstract
\abstractsection{ABSTRACT}

Some abstract content

\clearpage

% List of Figures and List of Tables
\listoffigures
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{LIST OF FIGURES}{}%
\listoftables
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{LIST OF TABLES}{}%

\clearpage

% Table of Contents
\tableofcontents 
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{CONTENTS}{}%

\clearpage

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecleader}{\protect\cftdotfill{\protect\cftsecdotsep}}}

%contents
\section{FIRST CHAPTER}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  figure
  \caption[EXAMPLE FIGURE]{example figure}
\end{figure}

\section{SECOND CHAPTER}
\begin{table}[ht]
  table
  \caption[EXAMPLE TABLE]{example table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Additionally, you have to insert (very strategically) entries into the ToC file to remove the leaders. I've done so and commented those locations above. The `.toc` file should now resemble:

```
\renewcommand {\cftsecleader }{\hfill }
\contentsline {section}{ABSTRACT}{}
\contentsline {section}{LIST OF FIGURES}{}
\contentsline {section}{LIST OF TABLES}{}
\contentsline {section}{CONTENTS}{}
\renewcommand {\cftsecleader }{\cftdotfill {\cftsecdotsep }}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}FIRST CHAPTER}{5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}SECOND CHAPTER}{5}
```

This way of adjusting the ToC-related content is necessary, since the ToC is processed as a whole before the rest of the document is set. You have to insert the adjustments within your document that correspond to the sequence within the ToC.